# How can one examine variables within a function's scope in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, scope, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Lab (I use Version 1.1.4), one can more or less debug notebooks by examining variables in that notebook's associated console (or other cells in that notebook).

For example the following code raises a ZeroDivisionError

```
   denominator = 0
   result = 9 / denominator
```

After an error such as this, I can type "denominator" into another notebook cell or into the associated console and see that denominator = 0.

So far so good

The problem arises when the offending code is inside a function such as

```
def someFunc():
   print('someFunc is executing')
   func_denominator = 0
   result = 9 / func_denominator    

someFunc()
```

When I call someFunc() a ZeroDivisionError is raised but I can't work out how to examine "func_denominator" or any of variables within the function's scope.

How does one examine variables within a function's scope in Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%debug` "magic" to help with this. Some hints over here: https://medium.com/@chrieke/jupyter-tips-and-tricks-994fdddb2057

Comment: Thank you, This does give access to the function scope variables. However, I can't seem to get it to work on "Create New View For Output". The new window is not interactive. The problem is then that the debug cell is often quite far away from the function code making it difficult to see the code you are debugging at the same time you are debugging it (the little debug snippet is insufficient). Is there a way to get %debug to work on a separate window? Or are there any alternatives to %debug? If this is all there is it will be more efficient to attach the pycham debugger

Comment: and code anything that needs debugging in Pycharm doing as little as possible in Jupyter. Certainly no function definitions. Seems like a shame...